# Tips on best way to programmatically create a Layout

Tags: android, android-layout

I am facing a scenario, where my main.xml has its main hierarchy written in XML but, the main data is coming from the server, so I need to compose the layout in runtime.

Please, take a look on this [screenshot](http://img263.imageshack.us/img263/9009/26059545.jpg) to better understand my scenario.

I shall have a Scroll View and then right under it, a Linear Layout. I retrieve this layout in my java class and create a new linear layout , so that I can create the new TextViews and Buttons like I draw inside LinearLayout 2. The end result is far from I expected and I honestly am not sure how I can accomplish this.

The code for is:

```
LinearLayout ll = (LinearLayout) findViewById(R.id.linearLayoutOffers); //this is the LinearLayout2 in SS

    //Creating the container that will have one business.
    LinearLayout containerMain = new LinearLayout(this);
    containerMain.setOrientation(LinearLayout.VERTICAL);
    containerMain.setLayoutParams(new LayoutParams(LayoutParams.MATCH_PARENT, LayoutParams.MATCH_PARENT));  
    containerMain.setGravity(Gravity.CENTER); 

    LinearLayout container1 = new LinearLayout(this);
    container1.setOrientation(LinearLayout.HORIZONTAL);
    container1.setLayoutParams(new LayoutParams(LayoutParams.MATCH_PARENT, LayoutParams.WRAP_CONTENT));  
    container1.setGravity(Gravity.CENTER);
    container1.setWeightSum(2);

    LinearLayout container2 = new LinearLayout(this);
    container2.setOrientation(LinearLayout.HORIZONTAL);
    container2.setLayoutParams(new LayoutParams(LayoutParams.MATCH_PARENT, LayoutParams.WRAP_CONTENT));  
    container2.setGravity(Gravity.CENTER); 
    container2.setWeightSum(1);

    LinearLayout container3 = new LinearLayout(this);
    container3.setOrientation(LinearLayout.HORIZONTAL);
    container3.setLayoutParams(new LayoutParams(LayoutParams.MATCH_PARENT, LayoutParams.WRAP_CONTENT));  
    container3.setGravity(Gravity.CENTER);
    container3.setWeightSum(1);

    TextView offerTitle = new TextView(this);
    offerTitle.setText(pOfferTitle);  
    offerTitle.setTextSize(14);
    //offerTitle.setPadding(10, 0, 10, 0);
    offerTitle.setLayoutParams(new LayoutParams(LayoutParams.WRAP_CONTENT, LayoutParams.WRAP_CONTENT, 1));

    Button redeemButton = new Button(this);
    redeemButton.setText("Usar");
    redeemButton.setLayoutParams(new LayoutParams(LayoutParams.WRAP_CONTENT, LayoutParams.WRAP_CONTENT, 1));
    //redeemButton.setPadding(10, 0, 10, 0);
    redeemButton.setTextSize(14);

    container1.addView(offerTitle);
    container1.addView(redeemButton);

    TextView mAddress = new TextView(this);
    mAddress.setText(pAddress);  
    mAddress.setTextSize(14);
    //mAddress.setPadding(10, 0, 10, 0);
    mAddress.setLayoutParams(new LayoutParams(LayoutParams.WRAP_CONTENT, LayoutParams.WRAP_CONTENT, 1));

    container2.addView(mAddress);

    TextView expiryDate = new TextView(this);
    expiryDate.setText(pExpiryDate);  
    expiryDate.setTextSize(14);
    //expiryDate.setPadding(10, 0, 10, 0);
    offerTitle.setLayoutParams(new LayoutParams(LayoutParams.WRAP_CONTENT, LayoutParams.WRAP_CONTENT, 0.6f));

    Button detailsButton = new Button(this);
    detailsButton.setText("Detalhes");
    detailsButton.setLayoutParams(new LayoutParams(LayoutParams.WRAP_CONTENT, LayoutParams.WRAP_CONTENT, 0.4f));
    //detailsButton.setPadding(30, 0, 0, 0);
    detailsButton.setTextSize(14);

    container3.addView(expiryDate);
    container3.addView(detailsButton);

    containerMain.addView(container1);
    containerMain.addView(container2);
    containerMain.addView(container3);

    ll.addView(containerMain);
```

Thanks for your time!
Felipe

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I think a far better way would be to use a [ListView](http://developer.android.com/resources/tutorials/views/hello-listview.html).
There you can define every row like you want. Also you can add or remove lines at runtime.
A ScrollView collapses easily when you want to add elements to it on runtime.

Comment: Can a line inside a ListView contain a TextView, Button and Image? Because every single example I can find, it's only adding plain text to this line.

Comment: Yes of course. The getView Method in your ListView-Adapter can return any Layout you want it to return. There is a good example how to start with ListView Adapters: http://www.mkyong.com/android/android-listview-example/

Comment: That approach doesn't seem to be good.
I need to define an array of String to get the name element...
In my scenario, I have 3 texts and two buttons... each button with different IDs to send to the server... 

Is there another way?

Comment: So you need to get an 2D Array or an ArrayList with your own Bean. The getView receives an int with the actual position of your item. So just get this int and look in your Array which ID the button needs to send and everything should be fine.